# Cannot find 'user_signed_in' [ Devise ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

*Rails version: 4.2.6, Ruby: 2.3.1*

I use:
`before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]`in my controller. I want to hide two buttons in my view:

```
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="two columns edit__buttons_column u-cf center_block">
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %>
          <%= link_to 'Delete', project_path(@project), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
```

But I receive an error: "**Cannot find 'user_signed_in**" It seems like helper methods don't work. I tried to use any other Devise methods, but the results are the same...

My routes.rb:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users
      resources :projects
      resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
      get 'welcome/index'
      root 'welcome#index'

      get '*path' => redirect('/')
    end
```

**user.rb**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    end
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the super class of your `ApplicationController`?

Comment: The error message that you're giving is uncommon for undefined methods. An error message starting with *Cannot find* in Rails is a typically an Record Not Found error... Post the exact error and at least a bit of relevant stack trace please.

Comment: @TimoSchilling Schilling ActionController::Base

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an odd error. The code appears to be correct as far as I can tell. I would ensure that you have installed Devise properly by running `rails generate devise:install`, run any pending migrations and then restart your rails server. The Devise Wiki indicates there can be strange errors like this if implemented and not restarted afterwards, so I would try that if you haven't.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
<% if current_user.present? -%>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="two columns edit__buttons_column u-cf center_block">
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %>
      <%= link_to 'Delete', project_path(@project), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end-%>
```

OR include this in application controller

`include Devise::Controllers::Helpers`

Comment: Cannot find 'current_user' :c

Comment: @MykolaGogol you have application helper at right place?

Comment: Do This again `$bundle exec rails g devise user` repeat the process somthing is missing as usually it works it docuemntation is followed correclty

Comment: @MykolaGogol try including this to `include Devise::Controllers::Helpers`  in controller

Comment: @WishZone `$bundle exec rails g devise user` didn't help.

Comment: @MykolaGogol

`include Devise::Controllers::Helpers` works? 
This is how devise implmented it 

`https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L46-49`

Comment: @MykolaGogol hmm then without looking at the code can not say what exactly you did wrong, I think you need to do fresh start, you need to add more details

Comment: Ok, tomorrow I will start a fresh project, hope this help, thanks, @WishZone

Comment: @MykolaGogol okay great some idiot devoted my answer, which is general purpose answer but in your case you did some mistake which is not identified with question and in our conversation, For sure do it again and you could use new rails and ruby versions... its having cool features